# Where do you see variables from command line in the vscode PowerShell debugger?

Tags: powershell, debugging, visual-studio-code

A lot of times when I'm programming in PyCharm I would use the evaluate expression functionality. If you do an assignment there ex:

```
some_variable = 5+5
```

it will immediately appear in the debugger variables list and you could see `some_variable` has a value of 10.

In vscode when you do something like:

```
$Test = Import-Csv -Path $SomePath
```

on the terminal command line that does not seem to appear in the variables list on the left. Is there a way to see PS variables you create in expressions in the debugger?

Comment: Not sure about the vscode debugger, but you can always enumerate all visible variables in the terminal with `Get-ChildItem variable:\ `